# Connection problem with PostgreSQL and Airflow (Built via Docker-compose)

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, airflow

I'm building a Airflow server from the official docker image:

```
curl -LfO "https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.3.0/docker-compose.yaml"
```

It creates an standard user (airflow) with standard password (airflow). I have been trying to connect to my Airflow DAG with a PostgresHook, but it keeps returning this:

```
[2022-05-18, 01:29:32 UTC] {base.py:68} INFO - Using connection ID 'postgres_db' for task execution.
[2022-05-18, 01:29:32 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1889} ERROR - Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 171, in execute
    return_value = self.execute_callable()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 189, in execute_callable
    return self.python_callable(*self.op_args, **self.op_kwargs)
  File "/opt/airflow/dags/etl_hover.py", line 35, in insert_data_to_table
    pg_conn = hook.get_conn()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/providers/postgres/hooks/postgres.py", line 113, in get_conn
    self.conn = psycopg2.connect(**conn_args)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server at "host.docker.internal" (192.168.65.2), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "***"
```

And, this is the connection:

[image]

As you can see, It is pretty much a standard connection (I have created succesfully an entry point with the database api_db, by the way. But It keeps telling me something about a wrong password. Any ideas?

Comment: host.docker.internal implies you are trying to connect to a Postgres database on the host out of the Docker Container. This host.docker.internal has given me many strange problems in the past (like: It just does not work on Linux). So, maybe better to add an extra container in the compose file with your own database.

Comment: What do you mean by the statement 'I have created succesfully an entry point with the database api_db'? There is no api_db schema in the docker-compose.yaml file you are starting up the services from.